# AWT graphics, object disappears briefly

Tags: java, graphics, awt, paint, thread-sleep

I am trying to learn how to make a graphics program, but some of the methods in java AWT are giving me unexpected results.

I have made a window, and I place a rectangle and that works. I want another figure, a circle, to appear after 1 second. I have tried the wait(x) method, which just places the circle immediately, and now I have tried the Thread.sleep(x) method, which does work, however I get the following behaviour:

After one second, the circle is displayed on the screen, but after a split second it disappears again, and another split second later it reappears and stays on the screen. I don't want it to temporarily disappear. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.awt.*;

class Example extends Canvas{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Example graphicProgram = new Example();  
        Frame graphics = new Frame();
        graphics.setSize(300, 300);
        graphics.add(graphicProgram);
        graphics.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Example(){
        setSize(200, 200);
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.fillRect(20, 150, 100, 100);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ex){
        }
        g.fillOval(150, 20, 100, 100); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. **Never** call Thread.sleep from within a paint type of method. Doing this will make your GUI completely unresponsive.
2. Yes, do call the super painting method from within your painting method (as per muhammad's answer).
3. You should not call `Thread.sleep(...)` from the event thread either as this too will freeze your application.
4. You should skip doing AWT and move to Swing.
5. When you do so, do your drawing in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of a JComponent or JPanel object.
6. Call the super's `paintComponent(g)` within your `paintComponent` method override.
7. Use a Swing Timer to do any delay or animation.

---

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawFoo extends JPanel {

   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final Stroke BASIC_STROKE = new BasicStroke(3f);
   private static final Color RECT_COLOR = Color.blue;
   private static final Color OVAL_COLOR = Color.red;
   private boolean drawCircle = false;
   private int rectX = 20;
   private int rectY = 150;
   private int rectWidth = 100;

   public DrawFoo() {
      int delay = 1000;
      Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            drawCircle = true;
            repaint();
         }
      });
      timer.setRepeats(false);
      timer.start();
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setStroke(BASIC_STROKE);
      g2.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
      g.fillRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectWidth);
      if (drawCircle) {
         g2.setColor(OVAL_COLOR);
         g.fillOval(rectY, rectX, rectWidth, rectWidth);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawFoo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawFoo());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

put this line as the first statment in your paint method `super.paint(g);`

it will be good to place also `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;` after above statment to use the improved performance and extra methods offered by Graphics2D